# Unable to refer to methods in another plugin

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a method in `classA` present in `PluginA`, I am able to compile and access this method in all the classes inside the same plugin.
When I try to access the method from another `pluginB` I get below error. Although I am able to refer and print enums in `pluginA` from `pluginB`.

```
\plugins\pluginB\mocks\classB.cpp:61: error: undefined reference to namespaceA::classA::methodA(int)

collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

- QT: 4.8
- IDE: QT creator 4.4.0
- OS: Windows 10

Comment: Do you mean you can print enums from `PluginA` from `pluginB`?

Comment: yes. sorry for the typo. edited the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If plugins are independent, you cannot directly call functions across them.
In this case, if you do need to call a function across plugins, you need to use `GetProcAddress` to retrieve the address of a particular function. However this only works for free functions declared with `extern "C"`:

```
// Somewher in pluginA
extern "C" void functionA() {}

// Somewhere in pluginB
using MyFunc = void(void);
MyFunc *pointer = GetProcAddress(module,TEXT("functionA"));
if (pointer)
    pointer(); // call "functionA()";
else
    qWarning("functionA() not found, pluginA not loaded");
```

Note that you may want to use `EnumProcessModulesEx()` to search in all possible loaded `module`.

If pluginB is linked to pluginA at compile time, that means that you should have `LIBS += -lpluginA` in the .pro file of your pluginB.
Also make sure you are using `__declspec( dllexport )` and `__declspec( dllimport )` on the `classA` declaration.

If you used Qt Creator wizard to generate your pluginA project, you should already have something like this in your code:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER

    #if defined(LIBRARY_A)
        #define LIBRARY_A_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define LIBRARY_A_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif

#else

    #define LIBRARY_A_EXPORT

#endif
```

Just make sure that classA definition looks like: `class LIBRARY_A_EXPORT classA`;